# Customizing colors – Invalid Face

Tags: colors, customization

I am trying to just adjust a few colors, without creating a whole theme. My lisp startup file contains:

```
(load-theme 'tsdh-dark t nil)
...
(set-face-foreground 'custom-variable-tag "White")
```

For some reason, the face `'custom-variable-tag` is not recognized during Emacs startup; but when I eval this Lisp code during an Emacs session, it works fine and changes the color as expected.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `M-x describe-face RET custom-variable-tag` to find out where the face is defined. It turns out to be defined in `cus-edit`. Presumably somebody loads `cus-edit` eventually, so that later on in the Emacs session it is defined and you can modify it. But it is probably not loaded early enough so that you can do the modification in your init file.

You can force it to be loaded:

```
(load-theme 'tsdh-dark t nil)
(require 'cus-edit)
...
(set-face-foreground 'custom-variable-tag "White")
```

or you can arrange for the modification to be done *after* it is loaded:

```
(load-theme 'tsdh-dark t nil)
...
(eval-after-load 'cus-edit 
    (set-face-foreground 'custom-variable-tag "White"))
```

In general, things need to be defined before they are used: that applies to variables, functions and faces and the solution is always the same as above: either load the library that defines the object *before* you modify it, or arrange for the modification to happen *after* the defining library has been loaded.