# org mode - suppress export to ascii

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-publish

I've looked through the manual but can't seem to find the answer. Is it possible to suppress the TOC when exporting to ascii, but have it export to html?

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT: Simpler answer

This answer is really along the same lines that the answer in the executive summary follows, but it is a bit more streamlined to make it easier for a new Emacs user to use. The Org mode file will not need the code blocks because we are not going to advise the function. Instead, we are going to change the global value of the `org-export-options-alist` variable in the init file. And since we are making changes to the init file, we are going to add the macro definition to it as well, so that it will *always* be available for every Org mode file.

That means that the only thing needed in the Org mode file to take advantage of this capability is the modified `#+OPTIONS` line:

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:{{{if-ascii-else(nil, t)}}}

* section
foo

* bar
bar
```

The modifications to the init file are: 1) to modify the global value of the `org-export-options-alist` value and 2) to add the definition of the `if-ascii-else` macro.

The modification of `org-export-options-alist` is bog-standard: we need to do it after `ox.el[c]` is loaded, since the variable is defined in that file, but that's what `eval-after-load` is for:

```el
(eval-after-load 'ox
   (setq org-export-options-alist
       (cons '(:options "OPTIONS" nil nil parse) 
             org-export-options-alist)))
```

This modifies the *global* value of `org-export-options-alist` but the effect on export is the same as in the "executive summary" answer.

Adding the macro similarly requires some code to be executed after the appropriate file is loaded:

```el
(eval-after-load 'ox
    (add-to-list 'org-export-global-macros
             '("if-ascii-else" . "(eval (if (org-export-derived-backend-p org-export-current-backend 'ascii) $1 $2))"))
```

`org-export-global-macros` is a list of macros available globally. See its doc string with `C-h v org-export-global-macros`.

After adding these two snippets to your init file, restart Emacs so they take effect and export normally: `C-c C-e t A` e.g

The advantage here is that you can copy these two snippets of code into your init file and run with it, without understanding what they do, but I hope you will study the rest of the answer and get at least a glimpse of how to do these things in the future.

---

[Original answer starts here.]

[This was harder than it should be, although there might be a better way to do it than what I provide below. I suggest you wait a few days to see if somebody comes up with a better answer.]

#### Executive Summary

Here's an Org mode file that will produce a TOC only if you are *not* exporting to `ascii`:

```
#+MACRO: if-ascii-else (eval (if (org-export-derived-backend-p org-export-current-backend 'ascii) $1 $2))

#+OPTIONS: toc:{{{if-ascii-else(nil, t)}}}

Options should be {{{keyword(OPTIONS)}}}

* section
foo

* bar
bar


* Code                                                  :noexport:

#+name: advice-add
#+begin_src elisp
  (defun my/org-export-dispatch (orig-func &optional arg)
     (let ((org-export-options-alist (cons '(:options "OPTIONS" nil nil parse) org-export-options-alist)))
       (funcall orig-func arg)))

  (advice-add 'org-export-dispatch :around #'my/org-export-dispatch)
#+end_src

#+name: advice-remove
#+begin_src elisp
 (advice-remove 'org-export-dispatch #'my/org-export-dispatch)
#+end_src
```

Before you press `C-e` to to start the export dispatcher, you will have to press `C-c C-c` on the first code block (the one named `advice-add`). You can check that the advice has been added with `C-h f org-export-dispatch` and checking the last line: it should say `This function has :around advice: ‘my/org-export-dispatch’.`
Then, you should be able to export normally: `C-c C-e t A` e.g to export to an `ascii` buffer or `C-c C-e h o` to export to an HTML file and open it.

Afterwards, you can remove the advice by pressing `C-c C-c` on the second code block (the one name `advice-remove`) to put everything back to normal. You can also leave the advice in force, assuming it causes no problems - you can even add it to your init file, so that it will be available in the future, after you have tested it thoroughly. You will have to make sure that `org-export-dispatch` is defined already before you can add the advice to it, either by doing a `(require 'ox)` or by doing the `advice-add` within an `eval-after-load`. See [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/74906/14825) for some details on a similar problem.

---

#### All the gory details

The idea is to use a [macro](https://orgmode.org/manual/Macro-Replacement.html) to set the `toc` option to either `nil` or `t`, depending on whether the export backend is (derived from) `ascii` or not. The following macro can do that:

```org
#+MACRO: if-ascii-else (eval (if (org-export-derived-backend-p org-export-current-backend 'ascii) $1 $2))

#+OPTIONS: toc:{{{if-ascii-else(nil, t)}}}

Options should be {{{keyword(OPTIONS)}}}
```

This is a modified version of a similar macro that I cribbed from [@fniessen's collection](https://github.com/fniessen/org-macros/blob/master/org/org-macros.setup#L23).

If you add the above to your file and try exporting, everything works, **except** that you still get a TOC even in ascii export. It turns out that macros are expanded in *certain* keywords, but *not* in the `#+OPTIONS` keyword. I added the last line for debugging, to make sure that the replacement does happen properly (it does) in normal context. It just does not happen where it would matter.

It turns out the the `org-export-as` function calls the macro processor [as follows](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/ox.el#n3069):

```el
    ...
    (org-macro-replace-all org-macro-templates parsed-keywords)
    ...
```

where `parsed-keywords` is the list of keywords where macro expansion *will* happen (see the doc string of `org-macro-replace-all` with `C-h f org-macro-replace-all`).

So I modified that line to

```el
    ...
    (org-macro-replace-all org-macro-templates (cons "OPTIONS" parsed-keywords))
    ...
```

and lo and behold! the exported output did not contain the TOC.

The trick now is to do the above without modifying the code explicitly. There are probably multiple ways to do that, but I figured that if I could change whatever variable was used to calculate `parsed-keywords` in `org-export-dispatch`, maybe I could `let`-bind the variable in an advice of the function.

The `parsed-keywords` variable is `let-bound` through the [following code in `org-export-as`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/ox.el#n3052):

```el
           ...
           (parsed-keywords
            (delq nil
              (mapcar (lambda (o) (and (eq (nth 4 o) 'parse) (nth 1 o)))
                  (append (org-export-get-all-options backend)
                      org-export-options-alist))))
           ...
```

which basically constructs a list of keyword names out of `org-export-options-alist`. Looking at the latter with `C-h v org-export-options-alist` shows that "OPTIONS" is indeed not included in it. `org-export-options-alist` is not a simple list of names however, so the modification is a bit more complicated:

```el
    (let ((org-export-options-alist (cons '(:options "OPTIONS" nil nil parse) org-export-options-alist)))
        (org-export-dispatch))
```

We cons an entry onto the front of `org-export-options-alist`, `let`-bind the result to `org-export-options-alist` and call `org-export-dispatch` with that `let`-binding in place. And... it works: if you go to your Org mode buffer and use `M-:` with the above expression, instead of using `C-e` which just calls `org-export-dispatch`, you can use `t A` e.g. to export to a buffer and you get no TOC.

We can now use the [`advice` mechanism](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) to add the above modification to `org-export-dispatch`. I like adding a `Code` section to the Org file itself (with a `noexport` tag, so that it is ignored by the exporter) and add code blocks that do the modifications I want:

```
* Code                                                   :noexport

#+name: advice-add
#+begin_src elisp
  (defun my/org-export-dispatch (orig-func &optional arg)
     (let ((org-export-options-alist (cons '(:options "OPTIONS" nil nil parse) org-export-options-alist)))
       (funcall orig-func arg)))

  (advice-add 'org-export-dispatch :around #'my/org-export-dispatch)
#+end_src
```

Pressing `C-c C-c` on the code block executes it, thereby defining the `my/org-export-dispatch` function and then adding it as an `around` advice to `org-export-dispatch`. The `my/org-export-dispatch` function `let`-binds the `org-export-options-alist` just as we did manually earlier, before calling the original function that was advised, i.e. `org-export-dispatch`.

I hope the step-by-step helps but you might have to read it a couple of times. In the meantime, the executive summary should suffice.

Comment: thanks.. way more complicated than I hoped for, but really appreciate your response.

Comment: PTAL at the "simpler answer" at the top. I think it will be easier to use.